# How do you code a <a href> in html to be called by a flash button?

Tags: file, hyperlink, flash-cs3

I am new to programming and am trying to use a flash button to open a link.  I embeded the .swf file in html and surround it with the a href tags as follows:

```
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com/submit.php?url=">
<object width="550" height="400">
<param name="movie" value="somefilename.swf">
<embed src="file:///c:/users/joe/desktop/projects/oRBsun.swf" width="550" height="400">
</embed>
</object>
</a>
```

Easy, but does not work.  So...how would I write script for what seems like an easy task?

Answer (score 0):

you can´t use the  tag around a swf file in HTML.
If you are using ActionScript 2.0 you could use the getURL() function in Flash.
Right-Click on the Button (you create in Flash) then click on "Actions".
Here you will find the getURL() function